# How library linking and header inclusion works with CMAKE

Tags: c++, cmake

I am newbie to the CMAKE. please forgive me if you found my question silly.

I have following scenario in my project.

I have to use library `libraryone` in my `librarytwo`

may CMakeLists.txt for librarytwo looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
find_package(libraryone REQUIRED)
add_library(librarytwo STATIC librarytwo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(librarytwo PUBLIC lib1::libraryone)
```

And my librarytwo.h and librarytwo.cpp looks like

librarytwo.h

```
#include <src/lib1/libraryone.h>
--------
-------
```

librarytwo.cpp

```
#include <librarytwo.h>
---------
--------
```

My libray two getting build properly.

Now I want to use librarytwo in librarythree

So my CMakeList.txt for librarythree looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
add_library(librarythree STATIC librarythree.cpp)
target_include_directories(librarythree PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURECE_DIR}/src/lib2}
target_link_libraries(librarythree PRIVATE librarytwo)
```

my librarythree.cpp and libraythree.h looks like

librarythree.h

```
#include <src/lib2/librarytwo.h>
--------
-------
```

librarythree.cpp

```
#include <librarythree.h>
---------
--------
```

But while building librarythree, I am getting error in librarythree.h saying `libraryone.h : No such file or directory`

So, it was working for librarytwo.h and I have linked librarytwo to librarythree.
So what I am missing ? help appreciated.

Comment: It seems that libraryone allows to include its header via `src/lib1/libraryone.h`, but including it via `libraryone.h` is not supported.

Comment: Wherever I include librarytwo.h, it says libraryone.h not found.

Comment: Again, it seems to be constraint of your libraryone, that its header should be included via `#include <src/lib1/libraryone.h>`, as you describe in the question post. As far as I understand your error message, it tells that including the file via  `#include <libraryone.h>` causes the error. If you want to make this inclusion to work, then you need to change scripts for libraryone.

Comment: libraryone is not in my scope. I can't change anything related to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're including `librarytwo.h`, which in turn includes `libraryone.h`. You need to add a `target_include_directories` statement in your library 3 that tells it where to find `libraryone.h`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct.  That is, there are some fancy things that you can do to get around this.  I haven't figured out how yet, but you can check out https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt on how they have worked around this.